# Xamarin.Forms Send Data To API as application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, x-www-form-urlencoded

I want to send the data to an api as **x-www-form-urlencoded** not as **json**. I usually send the data as json using newtonsoft.json nuget package, I searched but did not find any solution. Thansks in advance

Comment: Try to use [Refit](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit)

Comment: @cahyo I will search more and if nothing worked I;ll try ur solution. thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send string data and the content-type set to `x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
using(var content=new StringContent())
{
    content.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
    content.Headers.Add("Content-Type","x-www-form-urlencoded");
}
```

If your parameters is username and password you can do this:

```
string param="username=admin&password=123456";
var content=new StringContent(param,Encoding.UTF8,"x-www-form-urlencoded");
var client=new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress="https://localhost";
await client.PostAsync("/api/login",content);
```

Comment: how can I send the parameters? Suppose I have a class with username and password. how can i send them?

Comment: if u can post an example I will be greatful.